# Easiest way to simplify very big complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't know if this question has a solution, but I'll ask it anyway.I often come across complex numbers in the form

$$
   \frac{(a_0 + ib_0)}{(a_1 + ib_1)(a_2 + ib_2)(a_3 + ib_3)}
$$

but I need these in the normal form of

$$
    a + ib
$$

Now the way I solve this is that I multiply out the denominator and then rationalise the result but the problem is because the factors $a_i$ and $b_i$ are often a little complex this method is prone to mistakes.So I would like to know if there is an easier way I can do this by hand or if there is a way that I can check that my final answer is correct.

Comment: You just need to multiply your number and divide it by the conjugate number of the denominator!.

Comment: Try writing your complex numbers in polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$, where multiplication is fast, then converting back to $z=a+bi$ form. This is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: The question was whether or not there was an easier way than expanding the brackets.

Comment: @ Daniel Littlewood: In this case, you can try several forms of complex numbers: polar, trigonometric. But I believe that there is no other way than this. Can rewrite the denominator again here to see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brett Frankel points out, you have the following identity:
$$ a_i+i\cdot b_i = r_i e^{i\cdot \theta_i} $$
With $r_i^2 = a_i^2+b_i^2$ and $\theta = \arg(a_i+i\cdot b_i)$ where $\arg(\cdot)$ denotes the [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_%28mathematics%29).

From that it follows, that your expression can be rewritten as 
\begin{align} a+i\cdot b &= \frac{r_0e^{i\cdot \theta_0}}{r_1e^{i\cdot \theta_1}\cdot r_2e^{i\cdot \theta_2}\cdot r_3e^{i\cdot \theta_3}}
\\ &= \frac{r_0}{r_1\cdot r_2\cdot r_3} \cdot e^{i\cdot (\theta_0-\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3)}
\\ &=: r \cdot e^{i\cdot \theta}\end{align}

And to come back from polar coordinate we have the identity
$$  r \cdot e^{i\cdot \theta} = r ( \cos(\theta) +i\cdot \sin(\theta))$$
Which gives you $a$ and $b$.